# UITableview Section Header not showing text

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have added this code to my UITableViewController to return grey header sections.

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 30)];
   [headerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    return headerView;
}
```

however in doing this now I cannot see the header characters... do I need to add this as a subview? or is there another way of doing things?

I have  these methods adding the headers and the header text to the UITablView but when I use the above method I cannot see them anymore.

```
// Section headers
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{    
    return [sectionLetterArray objectAtIndex:section];
}

// Section header titles
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return sectionLetterArray;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you create your own `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection`, you have to create the UILabel or whatever, and fill in the text yourself, e.g.:

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 30)];
    [headerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];

    // Add the label
    UILabel *headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(kSectionTitleLeftMargin, 
                                                                     kSectionTitleTopMargin, 
                                                                     tableView.bounds.size.width - kSectionTitleLeftMargin - kSectionTitleRightMargin, 
                                                                     30.0 - kSectionTitleTopMargin - kSectionTitleBottomMargin)];

    // do whatever headerLabel configuration you want here

    headerLabel.text = [self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section];
    [headerView addSubview:headerLabel];

    // Return the headerView
    return headerView;
}
```

Clearly, change headerLabel to be set up anyway you want, but the key take-home message is that if you create your own view, you have to create the label and fill in the text yourself.

Comment: This is the correct answer. just in case it wasn't clear if you call viewForHeaderInSection it overrides titleForHeaderInSection. That is why the text doesn't show even though you thought you were setting it.

Comment: sorry for the late replyI was working on a bug i found and it was making me mental so I fixed it up... just. lol anyway I am getting this error Use of undeclared identifier 'kSectionTitleLeftMargin'

Comment: Well, you have to decide how you personally want your label positioned on your header. Define those four margin constants appropriately for your desired look and feel. Start with zero for all of them and start indenting to your heart's content. As an aside, I wouldn't have used a static height of 30, but rather programmatically determined the height, but I didn't want get too carried away here...

Comment: Just checked, and I use 20 for my left margin, and 10 for the other three margins. But your mileage may vary. I also programmatically determine the height by using NSString's sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode (and adding my top and bottom margins).

Comment: #define kSectionTitleLeftMargin 0
#define kSectionTitleTopMargin 0
#define kSectionTitleRightMargin 0
#define kSectionTitleBottomMargin 0

Answer (score 1):

When you implement that method, the default view, complete with the label, is replaced by what YOU return, so it's your task to add it a label with whatever text you want.

Comment: I have edited my question to show the methods I have for adding text.